# Binding datetimepicker to a html control

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm creating a control to which datetimepicker is bound. I've done binding it to the control. This is how I've done:

Html:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-6">Year-Month</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" id="year_month" name="year_month" class="form-control" placeholder="Year, Month">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

javascript:

```
jQuery('#year_month').datetimepicker({ format: 'YYYY-MM' });
                jQuery("#year_month").val(moment().format("YYYY-MM"));
                alert(jQuery("#year_month").val());
                jQuery("#year_month").on("change", function(){
                    alert("coming here!");
                });
```

The thing is, this is working properly when the page is loaded. ie the current year and current month is displayed correctly. I have to trigger a change event when I change the month or year. But, when I try to change the month or year, it shows, "TypeError: widget.find is not a function" error. What is wrong with this code? What should I do for the change event? These are the plug-ins I've added:

```
<script src="js/moment-with-locales.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
```

moment-with-locales.js is for displaying current year, month, date.
bootstrap-datetimepicker.js is for calender view.
And my jquery version is: jQuery v1.11.3.
Plug-ins added are:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
```

This is the order I've placed my references:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    <link href="css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="css/switch.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/notifIt.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/pace-theme-minimal.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.datatable/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>    
    <script src="js/select2.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.datatable/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.datatable/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.datatable/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.datatable/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.datatable/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.datatable/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.datatable/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.datatable/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.rowGrouping.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>    
    <script src="js/moment-with-locales.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/notifIt.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/pace.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.extend.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
```

Help me clearing this out.

Comment: jquery encourages functional programming in the style of $('#year_month').datetimepicker({ format: 'YYYY-MM' }).val(moment().format("YYYY-MM")).on("change", function(){ alert("coming here!"); });

Comment: Which datetimepicker are you using ? Is it this one https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ ?

Comment: I've shown you that. It's in the reference files itself.